# Comparing two lists of Django model instances

Tags: python, django

I have a rather complex use-case where I need to compare two lists of dictionaries, however there are a variety of different states that the lists can be in and ideally I would like to be able to handle all of them in one.

The background to this is that I have a form which is rendered as a table of checkboxes, and I am trying to get the difference between the initial data of the form and the `cleaned_data` being sent back when an update is made (i.e. checkboxes are checked or unchecked).

So typically the initial data will contain only the data for checked checkboxes, e.g.

```
initial_data = [<Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>]
```

where an Event object contains a id and a name, they can be the same as it could be the same event.

If a checkbox is unchecked then the `cleaned_data` might look like this:

```
cleaned_data = [<Event: Event object>, None, <Event: Event object>, None]
```

In this case I would like to get the events from the initial_data where there is None in the cleaned_data. The next use-case is that if checkbox is then checked the initial data may look like this:

```
initial_data = [<Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>]
```

and then cleaned data like this:

```
cleaned_data = [<Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>]
```

In this case I would like to return the events from the cleaned_data that don't match the initial_data.

There is also a third part which complicates things, if there is a row with no checked checkboxes it also shows up as None. So I also need to handle that:

```
initial_data = [<Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>]

cleaned_data = [<Event: Event object>, None, <Event: Event object>, <Event: Event object>]
```

So to clarify what I am trying to do is return the initial event data if there is a corresponding None in the forms `cleaned_data`, return the events and the Nones if there is a difference in the `cleaned_data` from the initial data and remove the Nones.

I have been trying to do it with something like this:

```
events = [[x for x in cleaned_data if x not in initial_data], [x for x in initial_data if x not in cleaned_data]]
```

but this only works for one of my use-cases (it works for the second case but for the first it returns the Nones rather than the events).

Any help with this would be much appreciated, as I feel I am pretty close but I just can't get it figured out in my head!

Thanks for your time.

P.S. This is part of `Django` application

**--EDIT--**

The form code looks like this:

```
class ActivityGroupInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = models.ActivityGroup
    fields = ['events',]
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0

    @property
    def widgets(self):
        return {
            'events': widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }

    def get_factory_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_factory_kwargs()

        kwargs.update({
            'widgets': self.widgets,
        })

        return kwargs


class ActivityGroupEventLink(NamedFormsetsMixin, UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model = models.Container
    fields = []
    template_name = 'main/link_activitygroupsevents.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    inlines = [ActivityGroupInline,]
    inlines_names = ['activitygroup_inline',]

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return models.Container.objects.first()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context['breadcrumbs'] = [
            {'name': 'Home', 'url': reverse_lazy('dashboard')},
            {'name': 'Link Activities to Events', 'is_active': True}
        ]

        all_events = models.Event.objects.filter(
            container=context['object'],
        ).all()

        context['events'] = { event.id: event for event in all_events }

        for form in context['activitygroup_inline'].forms:
            activitygroup_kcs = set(form.instance.key_characteristics.all())

            potential_event_ids = set()

            for event in all_events:
                event_kcs = set(event.key_characteristics.all())

                if event_kcs & activitygroup_kcs:
                    potential_event_ids.add(event.id)

            form.fields['events'].choices = models.Event.objects.filter(
                id__in=list(potential_event_ids)
            ).order_by('id').values_list('id', 'name')

        return context

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        self.object = form.save()

        for formset in inlines:
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)

            for inst in instances:
                initial_events = [] # This is code I added to work with the solution that I am now trying
                new_events = []
                for f in formset:
                    initial_events.append(f.initial['events']) # This is code I added to work with the solution that I am now trying
                    new_events.append(f.cleaned_data['events'].first())

                flat_initial = [item for sublist in initial_events for item in sublist] # This is code I added to work with the solution that I am now trying

                try:
                    event = next(event for event in new_events if event is not None) # This is what I was previously doing to find the relevant event but it only works if there is one column in the table.
                except StopIteration:
                    raise ValidationError('There must be at least one Activity Group linked to an event.')

                activityevent = inst.activityevent_set.filter(activity_group_id=inst.id, event_id=event.id)

                if activityevent.exists():
                    activityevent.delete()
                else:
                    new_activityevent = models.ActivityEvent.objects.create(
                        activity_group=inst,
                        event=event,
                    )
                    new_activityevent.save()

                inst.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

It also uses django-extraforms. Basically activity_group and event have an intermediate model activityevent so when a new link is made a new activityevent also needs to be made, and it needs to removed when a link is removed.

**--EDIT2--**

The form itself looks like this:

[image: Matrix form]

It's only the checkboxes which I am concerned about with this question

Comment: There don't seem to be any dictionaries here at all.

Comment: An Event object looks like `{'id': 1, 'container_id': 1, 'name': 'Delivery orders', 'description': 'Orders for delivery to customers premises', 'row_count': 6}`

Comment: But it's presumably a Django model instance, not a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, should I re-word the question then?

Comment: It would probably be clearer. Also I don't really understand why your cleaned_data contains None, or the difference between case two and three. Please post the code of the form.

Comment: There isn't really a difference between the second and third cases, I just thought it would be useful to know that that could happen as well. None will be returned if a checked checkbox is then unchecked (i.e. there was an event but it has been removed). The form creates a link between an event and something else so when you uncheck a checkbox you are essentially removing that link.

Comment: As I say, we really need to see some code, at least the clean method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question with the form the relevant part is in the forms_valid method